# Use Hibernates StatementInspector to modify sql inserts or deletions?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a hibernate config with a statement inspector:

```
 properties.put("hibernate.session_factory.statement_inspector", statementInterceptor);
```

The Inspector looks like:

```
public class SqlCommentStatementInspector implements StatementInspector {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(
                    SqlCommentStatementInspector.class
            );

    private static final Pattern SQL_COMMENT_PATTERN = Pattern
            .compile(
                    "\\/\\*.*?\\*\\/\\s*"
            );

    @Override
    public String inspect(String sql) {
        LOGGER.debug(
                "Executing SQL query: {}",
                sql
        );

        return SQL_COMMENT_PATTERN
                .matcher(sql)
                .replaceAll("");
    }
}
```

But the Inspector only catches selects, no inserts or deletions. Is there a way to also modify these statements? I want the sql-statement, no objects or entities.

I also tried the EmptyInterceptor class.